# Unable to Overwrite HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT registry value in C#

Tags: c#, registry

I am trying to overwrite the below values in registry on existing value of "Default". Written the below code but it is not updating the value. also code is not giving any error.

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ugmportalfile\Shell\Open\Command]
@="\"%TPR%\start_manager.bat\""

```
RegistryKey regKey=Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("ugmportalfile\\Shell\\Open\\Command", true);
//Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey regKey;
regKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot;
regKey.OpenSubKey(@"ugmportalfile\Shell\Open\Command");
regKey.SetValue("Default", @"%TPR%\start_manager.bat");
regKey.Close();
```

Comment: That code snippet stopped making sense after you tried to make it work.  It only shows up a "(Default)" in regedit.exe.  To set the unnamed value for a key you have to pass null or "" as the first argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OpenSubKey` does return a RegistryKey object, you are trying to modify a wrong key.

```
RegistryKey regKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot;
RegistryKey subkey = regKey.OpenSubKey(@"ugmportalfile\Shell\Open\Command", true); // Could be also Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot..OpenSubKey(@"ugmportalfile\Shell\Open\Command", true);
subkey.SetValue("Default", @"%TPR%\start_manager.bat");
subkey.Close();
```

You could also consider `using` code blocks 'cause of IDisposable interface.

Edit: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xthy8s8d(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. I have used your above code. but now it is giving error "The name 'regKey' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: I posted only the part that should be changed.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me the only issue is it is creating the new value with the name "Default" not overwriting the existing value. I am trying to overwrite the existing value of "Default".

Comment: I was able to overwrite the Default value by passing the blank instead of Default. like regKey.SetValue("", @"%TPR%\start_manager.bat");